# Can I know why? the value 5 is returned and assigned to the variable x, then printed. Lines 4 and 5 never execute

Tags: python

Can I know why?  the value 5 is returned and assigned to the variable x, then printed. Lines 4 and 5 never execute.

```
def weird():
    print("here")
    return 5
    print("there")
    return 10

x = weird()
print(x)
```

Comment: `return` *ends the function*.  Nothing after an unconditional `return` can possibly be executed.

Answer (score 1):

That's what `return` does. It *returns* execution to the caller of the function, without executing any more of the body of the function. If you intended to return both `5` and `10`, you would have to return a tuple.

```
def weird():
   print("here")
   print("there")
   return (5, 10)

x = weird()
assert x == (5, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because return will break the function and exit:

```
def weird():
    print("here")
    print(5)
    print("there")
    print(10)

weird()
```

This function will return the whole output:

```
def weird():
  s = ""
  s += "here\n"
  s += str(5)+"\n"
  s += "there\n"
  s += str(10)
  return s

x = weird()
print(x)
```

And if you want to return a list of [5,10]:

```
def weird():
    print("here")
    print("there")
    return [5,10]

x = weird()
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, a function will return a value, and after that the function will be terminated.

Hence, "Return 5" effectively terminates the function by returning the value "5". Hence the lines 4 and 5 are never executed.